# record count of entity datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How does one get the total count of records from entitydatasource in asp.net c#

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="entproducts" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="name=CommerceEntities" 
DefaultContainerName="CommerceEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
EntitySetName="products" Where="it.Berths=@dpberths" 
OrderBy="it.[id] DESC" EntityTypeFilter="" Select="" 
ondatabinding="entproducts_DataBinding" onselecting="entproducts_Selecting">
 <WhereParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dpberhs" Name="dpberths" 
         PropertyName="SelectedValue" DbType=int32 />
 </WhereParameters>

    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the "Selected" event;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.selected.aspx